# Fetching all database entries with their relationships using a Resource

Tags: laravel, eloquent

So, I'm currently trying to fetch every entry from one database table and returning them using an APIResource. I wanna also return every relationship of those entries.
Here is my controller:

```
public function all() 
    {

        return GameResource::collection(Game::all()->with('white_user', 'black_user', 'win_user')->get());
    }
```

And the corresponding Resource:

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'GmID' => $this->GmID,
            'White_user' => new UserPublicResource($this->whenLoaded('white_user')),
            'Black_user' => new UserPublicResource($this->whenLoaded('black_user')),
            'Winner' => new UserPublicResource($this->whenLoaded('win_user')),
            'Pgn' => $this->Pgn,
            'StartTime' => $this->StartTime
        ];
    }
```

I am aware that the Problem lies in the all() method which returns a collection which doesnt have a with() method.
Here is the error message:

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::with does not exist.

I am wondering if there is an easy way to do what I want to and I can't seem to find anything in the docs or anyone on the internet who wanted something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are calling with after fetching data which is collection and collection don't have with method call this way will work it will fetch all data from game table.

```
return GameResource::collection(Game::with('white_user', 'black_user', 'win_user')->get());
```